# How to make physical reset button require long press

Tags: linux, windows-10, case, winapi, physical-security

Is there a way to make my computer case's physical reset button only perform a reset after being pressed continuously for some number of seconds in a manner akin to my power button ? I want that to prevent accidental hitting.

Solutions for both Windows 10 and Linux will be accepted.

Comment: Do you mean the power button, or do you have an additional reset button?

Comment: you could do it only with a HW element which would short the output only if the input is pressed for some time. the reset button shorts two pins on the MB while the power button goes to the PSU (ATX format) while the AT PSUs in the past had a hard switch with on/off positions...

Comment: This is going to require the hardware support that function. This will require either an already existing setting in the BIOS or cobbling together some additional hardware that sits between the button and the board.

Comment: A simpler HW solution I've used: put a stick-on rubber bumper or thick tape next to the switch, to block an *accidental* push. Works with *any* OS.

Comment: @harrymc I do have an additional reset button yes.

Comment: The reset button is a hardware reset that directly connects to the circuits on the motherboard, so cannot be customized from Windows or Linux. It can't be changed, but it can be disconnected. It's not really required, as the power button usually can force a shutdown with a short press and an immediate power-off with a long press.

Comment: See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/molly-guard